# How to edit the Oracle 11G settings for PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, oracle11g

I have a jar file which uploads resource files in the Database i.e. Oracle 11G. I wanted to create a Jar file which uploads files in PostgreSQL, but getting the following error.

this is my context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName"><value>org.postgresql.Driver</value></property>
            <property name="url"><value>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DBNAME</value></property>
            <property name="username"><value>NAEM</value></property>
            <property name="password"><value>Ulol</value></property>
        </bean> 
    <bean id="sessionFactoryExt" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="lobHandler" ref="defaultLobHandler"></property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>
                    file1.hbm.xml
                </value>
                <value>file2.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">
                    auto
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

        <bean id="defaultLobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler" />

        <bean id="ResourceUploader" class="com.proj.ResourceUploader" scope="prototype">
        <property name="locationFolder" value="my folder local"></property>
        <!-- properties for module jars movement -->
        <property name="modulesReleaseFolder" value="my folder local"></property>
        <property name="jbossRootFolder" value="my folder local"></property>
        <property name="sourceTargetFolder">
        <map> <entry key="artifacts" value="com/proj/main"></entry>
            <entry key="runtime" value="com/proj/main"></entry>
            <entry key="lsb" value="com/proj/main"></entry>
            <entry key="thirdparty-artifacts" value="com/proj/main"></entry>
        </map> </property>
        <property name="moduleBackUpRequired" value="true"></property>


        <property name="excemptedResourceTypes">
        <list>
        <value>Cert</value>
        </list>
        </property>
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryExt"></property>

        <property name="resource">
            <map>
               <entry>*LOTS OF ENTRIES (RESOURCE FILEs)*</entry>
            </map>
        </property>

        <property name="wflow">
            <list>....</list>


        </property>

        </bean>
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory"><ref bean="sessionFactoryExt"/></property>
          </bean>
          <aop:config>
<aop:pointcut id="resourceUploader"
            expression="execution(* com.ResourceUploader.*(..))" />

        <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="resourceUploader"
            advice-ref="defaultTxAdvice" />
    </aop:config>
    <tx:advice id="defaultTxAdvice">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>


    </beans>
```

Error:

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2216)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)   at
>   org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)   at
>   com.unisys.stealth.framework.services.resourceconfig.serviceobject.ResourceUploader.uploadWorkflowTemplate(ResourceUploader.java:183)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.uploadWorkflowTemplate(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.unisys.stealth.framework.services.resourceconfig.serviceobject.StartUpload.main(StartUpload.java:86)
>   Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation
>   "tbl_fr_workflow_config" does not exist   Position: 349   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)    at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:106)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213)     ... 20 more

Comment: do you need to have multiple datasources like Oracle and Postgres ? Or are you migrating from Oracle to Postgresql ?

Comment: Are you getting any exception while configuring PostfreSQL? Please attach logs.

Comment: Hi @MebinJoe you can say its a migration process.

Comment: Could you please try with below xml. Please let me know if you need any help. Thank you

Comment: Hi @MebinJoe it seems the problem was with my importing style. But now it works with postgresql but it is throwing issues like: Yes
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)

Comment: SQLGrammarException is thrown because the SQL query generated by Hibernate has wrong SQL syntax. The way you built the query might be wrong. Could you please attach the exception and java code where you are getting the exception

Comment: @MebinJoe Hi, the errors are their listed. Sharing the code will be a bit hassle

Comment: "*ERROR: relation "tbl_fr_workflow_config" does not exist*" - apparently you did not create the necessary tables in the Postgres database

Comment: Do you have this table created in PostgreSQL? You need to specify the schema name in the properties

<prop key="hibernate.default_schema">SCHEMA_NAME</prop>

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name with that there is some issues with upper case-lower case characters, In my DB the table name is defined in Upper Case characters and my hbm files also they are in upper case. And I don't know how or where to resolve the issue.

Comment: @MebinJoe I am facing issues with the uppercase characters here for schema too

Comment: @devilboy477 Could you please make all lower-case including all schemas. If the Spring XML answer worked for you could you please mark as useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Spring XML Datasourse configuration for PostgreSQL

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.*" />

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname" />
            <property name="username" value="postgres" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
            <property name="connectionProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="socketTimeout">10</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
       </bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
            <property name="annotatedClasses">
                <list>
                    <value>com.example.model.ExampleClass</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
    </bean>

</beans>
```